# Importing dates from CSV with jOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jooq

I have a CSV file I'm trying to import via jOOQ's [`loadCSV`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/LoaderSourceStep.html#loadCSV%28java.io.InputStream%29) method. I'd like to import straight into a MySQL database with a [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) column, but my CSV file has dates formatted as `YYYYMMDD` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`. Is there any way I can pass a custom date format (or date parser) to jOOQ for the import process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.3, there is no support for such data type transformations in the loader API. But I have registered [issue #3221](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3221) to add support for this useful feature. I suspect that something like this should be feasible (Java 8 syntax):

```java
ctx.loadInto(AUTHOR)
   .loadCSV(csv)
   .fields(AUTHOR.ID, AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
   .values(
      row -> AUTHOR.ID.getDataType().convert(row[0]),
      row -> row[1].split(" ")[0],
      row -> row[1].split(" ")[1]
   )
   .execute();
```

Contributions welcome, of course ;-)